# Sorround highlighted word with symbol Android Studio

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

If I have a word highlighted in android studio, is there any shortcut to surround that word with symbols e.g quotation marks or brackets?

E.G From John to "John" or Mary to (Mary)

Am aware of only Ctrl + Alt + T which surrounds the word with some functions and expressions from the options.

Comment: HIghlight/Double click the word -> type " or (

Comment: @OneCricketeer,  that deletes it and changes the entire word to ( / '....but it works that way in many other IDES

Comment: Seems to work in my IntelliJ with the Android plugin. Doubt Android Studio would rebind the keymap for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a configuration that should be on by default, don't know why you don't have it.

`preferences/Editor/Smart Keys`

Enable the option (check the checkbox)

```
Surround selection on typing quotes or braces
```

In the screenshot below is the seventh option from top to bottom.

[image]

Comment: thanks alot, that has just saved a whole lot of time